# Headers disappear when after overriding TableView.Scrolled

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have been in a pickle with this problem for a while now. When I try to manually handle how my table behaves while scrolling, everything works fine, except all my section headers disappear. What I tried to do was make the scroll view expand after I have scrolled for X number of points. The headers are not visible from the very start, but when I comment the override out, my headers are there as normal. Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this and make my section headers appear ?

A sample of my code is as follows :

```
    dialog.TableView.Scrolled += delegate {
if (dialog.TableView.ContentOffset.Y > this.View.Frame.Height)
{
dialogView.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,320,this.View.Frame.Height);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you subscribe to `Scrolled` on a `UITableView`, it will likely overwrite the underlying `UITableViewSource` that tells it how many sections/rows there are, etc.

It looks like you are using MonoTouch.Dialog, is the table simple enough where you could use a normal `UITableView` for this case? There is a `Scrolled` method you can override on `UITableViewSource`instead of using the C# event.

Comment: The problem is, it's not simple. The sections are custom, with custom headers and a tap event, the elements are also custom so basically it would be a ton of work to rewrite all that for this purpose :/

Comment: This is why I normally avoid MonoTouch.Dialog, you will have to look at the source and see if there is a way you can subclass the underlying `UITableViewSource` that dialog uses. If you had made the `UITableView` by hand, it would be easy. Maybe someone else can chime in with a solution, sorry.